# React Native: How to get length of an array from an imported JSON file?

Tags: json, react-native

I want to get the length of a JSON array from a imported file, but it returns undefined. I can access any elements from it. I guess the issue is the "books" here is not an array?

book.json:

```
[
  {
    "author" : "Bill",
    "total_chapters" : 14,
  },
  {
    "author" : "Chan",
    "total_chapters" : 29,
  },
:
]
```

App.js:

```
import * as books from './assets/book.json';

const author = books[60].author; //returns author
console.log('#books: ' + books.length); //undefined
console.log('books is ' + books.constructor); // Books is function Object() { [native code] }
console.log('books: ' + books); //books: [object Object]
```

Comment: what is the log for `books`?

Comment: books: [object Object]

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(books))`?

Comment: For completeness, can you add the structure of your `books.json` in your question?

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the hints form @snjmhj. The books is an object and the length can be obtained in this way:

```
Object.values(books).length
```